# google OAuthCallbackError signin?error=OAuthCallback

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, prisma, next-auth

I am adding next-auth with google provider to my next.js project in developement mode, but I am geeting this error on the browser URL :  http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback
and Try signing in with a different account message on the screen.
and
after signing in with signIn('google') everytime the following error appears in my terminal in vscode:

```
[next-auth][warn][NEXTAUTH_URL]
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#nextauth_url
data unauthenticated
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error JWT expired, now 1675094480, exp 1675094221 {
  error: RPError: JWT expired, now 1675094480, exp 1675094221
      at Client.validateJWT (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:956:15)
      at Client.validateIdToken (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:745:60)
      at Client.callback (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:488:18)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async oAuthCallback (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:129:16)
      at async Object.callback (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:52:11)
      at async AuthHandler (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:201:28)
      at async NextAuthHandler (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:24:19)
      at async D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:60:32
      at async Object.apiResolver (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:372:9)      at async DevServer.runApi (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:488:9)
      at async Object.fn (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:751:37)
      at async Router.execute (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:253:36)
      at async DevServer.run (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:384:29)
      at async DevServer.run (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:743:20)
      at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\React_prj\ChatApp\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:322:20) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'JWT expired, now 1675094480, exp 1675094221'
}
```

everytime on the browser I see the following image (Try signing in with a different account.)even trying with another account I get this image in the browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAL1I.jpg)

also, I use prisma as the adapter as well

the following are my codes:

```
[...nextauth].ts

import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import prisma from '../../../lib/prismadb';

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
});
```

prismadb.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

const client = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prisma = client;

export default client;
```

schema.prisma

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("MONGODB_URI")
 
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"

}

model Account {
  id  String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.String
  access_token       String?  @db.String
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.String
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id  String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id  String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  id  String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

and .env.local

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=46255473************od0rt849b.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=GOCSPX-*************I7SNBuJ6

MONGODB_URI =mongodb://localhost/chatapp
```

I tried many othersolution provided on the google and other providers but I cannot fix this issue.
please help
thx

I tried to login with next-auth with google as the provider and prisma as the adapter, but I get callback error

Comment: Your JWT expired Mon Jan 30 2023 15:57:01 GMT+0000.   You need to request a new one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You must add These props in you `env` file:

```
GOOGLE_ID = 89249145874417-vnb9dc2uh44peu40ef7l67f3eohgdfsfsflcfm.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = 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
MONGODB_URI =mongodb+srv://usernamepassjPBn@cluster0.7c7hshc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
NEXTAUTH_URL =http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL =http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET =o6jb9zMVmPUCm+YArIy7zfFjTIRr4566DuMZMcgjsnMXnTA=
```